# Express's custom fields cannot be found in routes

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have an extended type in `customExpress.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user: {
      id: string;
    };
  }
}
```

And also handled it in tsconfig.json:

```
 ...
 "typeRoots": ["src/customExpress.d.ts", "node_modules/@types"],
  "files": ["src/customExpress.d.ts"],
 ...
```

I am able to use it directly in a middleware from the express app:

```
const app = express();
app.use('/authUrl', authenticationMiddleware);
```

With the following definition:

```
const authenticationMiddleware = (req: express.Request, _: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction): void => {
 ...
 req.user = {id: 'aaaaa'}
 next();
}
export default authenticationMiddleware;
```

However the following will not work:

```
const authorize = (req: express.Request, _: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction): void => {
 ...
 if (!req.user.id) {
   next(new Error('not authorized'));
 } else {
   next();
 }
}
```

When the following usage:

```
const routes = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

routes.get('/', authorize, handler.listAll);
```

The above codes will give error:

```
authorize.ts(16,17): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'.
```

So it complains about the usage of `req.user` that I defined in the authorize.ts file.

Basically, if I use the middleware in the express object, the custom express object works fine, but if I want to use the custom express in a route object, it won't work. My guess is that the way the `routes` object is created (through `express.Router`) will not recognize my custom express and falls back to the default express object, therefore the custom fields will not work.

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized the problem comes to the way it was used to run:

```
"start:stable": "rm -rf dist && npm run build && node -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/src",
"build": "tsc",
"start": "nodemon"
```

The problem is while the `npm run build`, which is basically `tsc` builds the codes successfully. However the second part, `ts-node` tries to build it again. However when it was building, the default `tsconfig.json` location is supposed to be within the target folder which is `dist/src` and it is of course not that. `tsc` will not deal with the `tsconfig.json` file as configured so. Therefore, `ts-node` fails to process the codes because it doesn't have the typeRoot definition provided in the `tsconfig`.

The solution is, since I am already doing `tsc` before the `ts-node`, there is no need to repeat the same work, and `ts-node` can just do the transpiling for `node`.

The answer is to change the `start:stable` command to:

`rm -rf dist && npm run build && node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/src`

Also something interesting that I find: by default, `ts-node` does not support `files` field of `tsconfig`. Since I am adding custom type merging, `files` is required and the way to do is to put a `--files` flag when running `ts-node`.

There are resources and inspirations about this topic here:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#programmatic

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/782

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but type definitions are just something to be checked at compile time, there is not type at runtime because js is run, so if there is no user object in req, it throws error.

to do what you want, I think it's better to use passport, it does your auth and also attaches a user object when user is authenticated.